# Utilization of monetize format

Tags: excel, vba, format

I have a problem with the VBA monetize format. 
I have this code (which is a small part of a long long one) :

```
For i = 2 To (k + 1)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 5) = Format(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 5), " #,##0 €")
For j = 7 To 11
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, j) = Format(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, j), " #,###0 €")
Next
Next
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(k + 1, 12) = Format(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(k + 1, 12), " 0#,##0 €")
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Columns("A:M").AutoFit
```

Each time my value is smaller than 1000, the code displays just the value and without the € sign, but when it's bigger than 1000, I have no problem. I can't understand why. I tried to change my format ("#,##0.0 for example, but I doesn't display what I want ..)

Any suggestions ?
Thank you :)

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 5).NumberFormat = "[$€-x-euro2] #,##0.00"

Comment: Note that you can use the macro recorder whilst doing format cells currency and selecting the appropriate currency format to get the correct code, particularly if you want a different kind of euro/euro layout.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are from France, as noted on your profile, probably this is the best solution for you:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Style = "Currency"
```

It would use the automatic currency format, which is exactly what you need - 2 numbers after the thousand's separator and the EUR sign.